# Nagios Check showing Wrong Output, while plugin in remote System showing correct output

Tags: nagios

I have created a `check_pm2.sh` script to check **pm2** status on Remote server. It's giving correct output on Remote server. While calling it from Monitoring server I am getting wrong output. Please check the below command output.

Monitoring Server:

```
grep check_pm2status /usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/10.10.1.80.cfg 
      check_command check_nrpe! check_pm2status

./check_nrpe -H 10.10.1.80 -c check_pm2status

PM2 service is not running
```

Remote System:

```
grep check_pm2status /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg 
command[check_pm2status]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_pm2.sh


/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_pm2.sh

PM2 Service is running
```

Script is given below, **PM2STATUS**  variable  declared in below script  is getting output `0` from Monitoring server and `1` from Remote Server while running manually

```
PM2STATUS=`pm2  status | grep online | awk '{print $10}'|wc -l`

if [ $PM2STATUS -gt 0 ];then
   echo "PM2 Service is running"

   exit 0

else

   echo "PM2 service is not running"
   exit 2

fi
```

Comment: are you running the manual test as the nagios/nrpe user?

Comment: @Keith I tried to run manual test as nagios and root user from Monitoring server but getting wrong output "PM2 service is not running"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any difference with the result with nagios user and root user in the remote system for below command?

```
pm2  status | grep online | awk '{print $10}'|wc -l
```

Comment: yes, output is different for nagios user  and root in Remote system.

Comment: nagios@ip:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_pm2.sh 
0
PM2 service is not running

Comment: root@ip:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_pm2.sh
1
PM2 Service is running

Comment: Thanks Issue solved .User has no privilege to run command pm2 status

Comment: Glad that issue is solved.